# Suggested books that have an extensive treatment on Summation Notation

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

at the moment I'm looking for a book that has the following properties:

1. Is accessible to math undergraduates, preferably not much higher than first or second year undergraduates.
2. Treats summation notation at length in one or more of its chapters, going over such topics as change of index/variable, double summation, summation in which the index of summation is a set or contains some inequality. Exercises are very much preferred, and longer treatments are preferred over shorter treatments (short is certainly anything less than 5 pages).
3. Is not Knuth's *"Concrete Mathematics"*.
4. Does not cost more than 150 USD, ideally not more than 90 USD.
5. Is a ***book***. I'm well-acquainted with various online sources. I am explicitly looking for a book.

Kenneth Rosen in his Discrete Mathematics text treats summation notation, both double and with change of index, but only in passing at the start, and barely spends any time on this in the exercises. In contrast, Epp in her Discrete Mathematics text spends more time discussing summation notation, but unfortunately doesn't treat double summation or multiple summation, which is one of my requirements.

I hope some of you have any book suggestions.

Comment: Since it might be relevant to other choices, what’s the objection to Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott No reason in particular except for the fact that Im looking for an alternative, more or less because Knuth's level of sophistication might be just a little bit above the general level I'm aiming at. In addition to that I'm asking this because I'm hoping there's a discrete math or sequences & series book out there that devotes some time to this topic, as opposed to Knuth's book which in many ways isn't really discrete mathematics. Either way it's good to have alternatives, if just for the sake of diversity and freedom of choice.

Comment: I have never seen any book devote more than a few pages to this, and often they don't devote any space to it. On the other hand, if each sum is over a consecutive set of integers, there are parallels with working with double integrals. If the end points of each sum (integral) are fixed (i.e., do not depend on any other index (variable of integration), then you can switch the order of the summation (integral). If, however, one or both endpoints of inner sum (integral) depend on an index of an outer sum (integral), then you have to be very careful if you want to switch the other of the sum.

Comment: If you find a calculation confusing, I suggest trying to write out in full detail examples where each sum has only 2 or 3 terms in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get accustomed with the summation convention consult the first few chapters in most undergraduate relativity books. 
Dalarsson and dalarsson - tensors, relativity and cosmology was the book that brought everything together for me in terms of relativity and hence Tensors, index notation, Einstein summation convention. 
Ray d'Inverno -Introducing Einsteins relativity is another example.

Alternatively, vector calculus books will introduce index notation and summation convention.

What subject are you learning it for would also help to put it into context.  It will be difficult (IMO) to find a book that deals solely with this topic as it's only a very small fish in a massive pond.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll look into it. As to your closing passage: I'm not looking for a book that deals solely in this topic, that would be impossible. Instead, I'm looking for a book that devotes a chapter or a section to this topic.

Comment: A lot of relativity books will deal with it at least for a couple of pages. Good luck

Comment: I got the impression from Luke's question that he is interested in lower level treatments of summation notation (such as can be found in older college algebra books, and in differential equations books where power series solutions are covered), not something for the Einstein summation convention used in classical tensor analysis. If I'm wrong, he should probably edit his question to reflect this.